# Error Message when compiling

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;

public class ProgramData8
{

   public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
   {

      StackClass stack = new StackClass();
      QueueClass queue = new QueueClass();
      IntElement x = new IntElement(0);
      int num;

      StringTokenizer tokenizer;
      BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
      System.out.print("Please enter the numbers.");

      tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(keyboard.readLine());
      stack.push(x);
      queue.addQueue(x);
      num = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());

      while(num != -999)
      {
         x.setNum(num);
         switch(num%4)
         {
            case 0: stack.push(x);
               break;
            case 1: 
               if(!stack.isEmptyStack())
               {
                  System.out.println("Stack Element = " + stack.top());
                  stack.pop();
               }
               else
                  System.out.println("Sorry, the stack is empty.");
               break;
            case 2: queue.addQueue(x);
               break;
            case 3: 
               if(!queue.isEmptyQueue())
               {
                  System.out.println("Queue Element = " + queue.front());
                  queue.deleteQueue();
               }
               else
                  System.out.println("Sorry, the queue is empty.");
               break;
         }
         num = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
      }
      System.out.println("Stack Elements: " );
      while(!stack.isEmptyStack())
      {
         System.out.print(stack.top() + " " );
         stack.pop();
      }
      System.out.println();
      System.out.print("Queue Elements: " );
      while(!queue.isEmptyQueue())
      {
         System.out.print(queue.front() + " " );
         queue.deleteQueue();
      }
      System.out.println();
   }
}
```

I keep getting the following errors.

```
ProgramData8.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
      StackClass stack = new StackClass();
      ^
  symbol:   class StackClass
  location: class ProgramData8
ProgramData8.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
      StackClass stack = new StackClass();
                             ^
  symbol:   class StackClass
  location: class ProgramData8
ProgramData8.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
      QueueClass queue = new QueueClass();
      ^
  symbol:   class QueueClass
  location: class ProgramData8
ProgramData8.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
      QueueClass queue = new QueueClass();
                             ^
  symbol:   class QueueClass
  location: class ProgramData8
ProgramData8.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
      IntElement x = new IntElement(0);
      ^
  symbol:   class IntElement
  location: class ProgramData8
ProgramData8.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
      IntElement x = new IntElement(0);
                         ^
  symbol:   class IntElement
  location: class ProgramData8
6 errors

 ----jGRASP wedge2: exit code for process is 1.
 ----jGRASP: operation complete.
```

Comment: Have you linked into what `cannot find symbol` means?

Comment: Probably because `StackClass`, `QueueClass` and `IntElement` don't exist in your program.

Comment: So...what *are* those classes?  Java is asking the same question that any of us would be, given that you've only shown us one class which isn't related to any of the others you've got here.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with `user3414693`

For using this classes you need to do one of this.(May be some other ways also be there)

1.Keep them in same package and better to make them public

2.Keep all this classis in One File(*Not recommended*).

3.Use `package` concept to put all this classes in same directory and than `import` that package.

*(Sorry if i am missing something)*

Comment: Good way to come up with the error ;-) And yes you dont miss anything!

Comment: Yes I see that. And thats why I said a Good way to come up with error!

Answer (score 0):

> Cannot find symbol

This error means that the variable is either not declared, or does not exist in your scope.

Here the classes you refer are not in your scope. Import them. In eclipse IDE, use

> control + Shift+ O

to import classes.

In you case, you have not imported the custom classes, You have only these imports:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
```

you need to import `StackClass`,  `QueueClass` and all other Custom Classes.